# How to redirect site to paypal mobile and desktop version from e-commerce?

Tags: paypal, e-commerce, opencart

can anyone tell me how to redirect my e-commerce to paypal, i have an e-commerce with Opencart and i want to redirect to paypal desktop version if user is from desktop and i want redirect user to mobile version of paypal when user is from mobile device,

thank you in advance.

Comment: I need it for paypal standard, please let me know if you have any idea.

Comment: Even for PayPal Standard you would be using SetExpressCheckout so the below URLs should work (am assuming that you are using Buttons and using SetExpressCheckout) . If otherwise please explain your flow and implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using express checkout

For Mobile use

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?**cmd=_express-checkout-mobile**&token=tokenValueReturnedFromSetExpressCheckoutCall

For Desktop use

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?**cmd=_express-checkout**&token=tokenValueReturnedFromSetExpressCheckoutCall

Reference docs

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/mobile/gs_MEC/

and

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-singleItemPayment-curl-etc/